# java array printing wedge pattern

Tags: java

I have to write a method where it takes in an integer (shown below). for example if n was 3, it would print 
[1,2,3,2,1] 
and a 5 would print 
[1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
need help with second for loop!

```
public static int[] createWedge(int n) {
    //precondition:  n > 0
    int[] arr = new int[n+n-1];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for(int g = i; g < n; i--) {
        arr[g] = g - 1;
    }

    //dummy return value
    return arr; 
}
```

any help would be great. thanks!

Comment: my second for loop is probably wrong, need to fix that!

Comment: Yeah, but you are so close. Can you not just step thru with the debugger to see where your mistake is? Take a look at the second for loop. Where do you ever modify `g`? Why are you decrementing `i`? I think you can figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Iterate through the first half 1-n then second half n-1 to 1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     arr[i] = i + 1;
int j = n;
for (int g = n - 1; g > 0; g--)
     arr[j++] = g;
```

j could also be called position because it keeps track of the position in the array that is being set to the value.

Comment: tried it and it works, but not sure why it works.. can you explain it for me? :)

Comment: For sure! First do your loop... You know why that works. Then set a dummy variable to n so you can keep the position of the array you are adding to. It should be at n because of the loop you just went through. now increase j so we keep the position. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer was already posted by Jase, but I'm rewriting it slightly to see if it helps you understand

```
public static int[] createWedge(int n) {
    int[] arr = new int[n+n-1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         arr[i] = i + 1;
    for (int g = n - 1, j = n; g > 0; g--, j++)
         arr[j] = g;
    return arr;
}
```

Just like in the first loop, we need one counter that keeps going up. This is our position in the array. It's called `j` in Jase's solution and this one.

But we also need another counter going down. This is the number we put in the array. It's counting down from n to 1. That's what `g` is. We stop when `g` equals 0. That's why we have the continue condition `g > 0`.

Your first for loop was easier because both counters where the same namely `i`. It went up for position in the array and for the value to put in the array.